# Flask in Windows error message

Tags: python, flask

This is a snippet from my code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
```

And I get this error msg (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJNdZ.png).

[image]

How can I  solve this, because I think forms.py and flask.ext  is not a module...

I installed every module what is want to use for my program ...

Comment: Please, paste your console output (error message) as text (and not a picture) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail` to `from flask_mail import Message, Mail`.

Please referrer to docs on how to use/import extensions: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/extensions/. And `flask-email` (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) and `flask-wtf` (http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#quickstart) docs.

**EDIT**

In `intro-to-flask\forms.py` change `from flask.ext.wtf import ...`  to `from flask_wtf import ...`

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Now I get this   No module named  'flask_ext_wtf'

Comment: @FerencKovacs edited.

Comment: OKAY cool!! :D 

It works 

From version 0.9.0, Flask-WTF will not import anything from wtforms, you need to import fields from wtforms.